# NestedScrollerView inside RecyclerView not scrolling the content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using simple RecyclerView on android. I have set a few NestedScrollerView child using an adapter. Both have scrolling orientation in vertical. But when I am trying to scroll child content in NestedScrollView, it does not scroll instead the parent Recycler view is scrolling.
My parent layout is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.messenger.nes.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

The child layout is

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp">
<ImageView
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/img1" /></android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Afterthat I am simply creating new child views adapter and adding to the  recyclerview.
However, when I am replacing recylerview with list view the scrolling works well in the nestedscrollview. Do the nested scrolling not work inside RecyclerView?

Comment: Have you checked this page? : https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/scrollable-nestedscrollviews-inside-recyclerview-ca65050d828a

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement that.